# Help me understand this Scala code: scalaz IO Monad

Tags: scala, monads

Here's the code I'm trying to understand (it's from http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/scalaz-tutorial-enumeration-based-io-with-iteratees/):

```
object io {
  sealed trait IO[A] {
    def unsafePerformIO: A
  }

  object IO {
    def apply[A](a: => A): IO[A] = new IO[A] {
      def unsafePerformIO = a
    }
  }

  implicit val IOMonad = new Monad[IO] {
    def pure[A](a: => A): IO[A] = IO(a)
    def bind[A,B](a: IO[A], f: A => IO[B]): IO[B] = IO {
      implicitly[Monad[Function0]].bind(() => a.unsafePerformIO,
                                        (x:A) => () => f(x).unsafePerformIO)()
    }
  }
}
```

This code is used like this (I'm assuming an `import io._` is implied)

```
def bufferFile(f: File) = IO {   new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)) }

def closeReader(r: Reader) = IO {   r.close }

def bracket[A,B,C](init: IO[A], fin: A => IO[B], body: A => IO[C]): IO[C] = for { a <- init
      c <- body(a)
      _ <- fin(a) }   yield c

def enumFile[A](f: File, i: IterV[String, A]): IO[IterV[String, A]] =  bracket(bufferFile(f),
          closeReader(_:BufferedReader),
          enumReader(_:BufferedReader, i))
```

Let's start with the `bufferFile` definition. Am I correct in thinking that the `apply` method of io.IO is called? That `apply` method takes a parameterless function that returns a value (correct?). I guess this is where I'm stuck. Can someone explain how the definition of `bufferFile` works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are right, well almost; `io.IO.apply` gets called with a so called "by name" parameter which is basically a function which takes nothing (`Unit`) and returns `A`. The cool thing about is that when you pass an instance of `A` directly like `new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))`, it will be converted to something like `() => new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))`.

As a result of `apply` you get an instance of an `IO[BufferedReader]` which defines a method `def unsafePerformIO` which simply returns the instance of the captured `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing [agilesteel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797926/agilesteel)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404495/help-me-understand-this-scala-code-scalaz-io-monad/7404683#7404683), the code

```
def bufferFile(f: File) = IO {   new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)) }
```

Is equivalent to

```
def bufferFile(f: File) = new IO[A] {
  def unsafePerformIO = { new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)) }
}
```