# Help me understand this Scala code: scalaz IO Monad and implicits

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

This is a followup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404495/help-me-understand-this-scala-code-scalaz-io-monad) question.

Here's the code I'm trying to understand (it's from http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/scalaz-tutorial-enumeration-based-io-with-iteratees/):

```
object io {
  sealed trait IO[A] {
    def unsafePerformIO: A
  }

  object IO {
    def apply[A](a: => A): IO[A] = new IO[A] {
      def unsafePerformIO = a
    }
  }

  implicit val IOMonad = new Monad[IO] {
    def pure[A](a: => A): IO[A] = IO(a)
    def bind[A,B](a: IO[A], f: A => IO[B]): IO[B] = IO {
      implicitly[Monad[Function0]].bind(() => a.unsafePerformIO,
                                        (x:A) => () => f(x).unsafePerformIO)()
    }
  }
}
```

This code is used like this (I'm assuming an `import io._` is implied)

```
def bufferFile(f: File) = IO {   new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)) }

def closeReader(r: Reader) = IO {   r.close }

def bracket[A,B,C](init: IO[A], fin: A => IO[B], body: A => IO[C]): IO[C] = for { a <- init
      c <- body(a)
      _ <- fin(a) }   yield c

def enumFile[A](f: File, i: IterV[String, A]): IO[IterV[String, A]] =  bracket(bufferFile(f),
          closeReader(_:BufferedReader),
          enumReader(_:BufferedReader, i))
```

I'm now trying to understand the `implicit val IOMonad` definition. Here's how I understand it. This is a [scalaz.Monad](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.2/doc/index.html#scalaz.Monad), so it needs to define `pure` and `bind` abstract values of the `scalaz.Monad` trait.

`pure` takes a value and turns it into a value contained in the "container" type. For example it could take an `Int` and return a `List[Int]`. This seems pretty simple.

`bind` takes a "container" type and a function that maps the type that the container holds to another type. The value that is returned is the same container type, but it's now holding a new type. An example would be taking a `List[Int]` and mapping it to a `List[String]` using a function that maps `Int`s to `String`s. Is `bind` pretty much the same as `map`?

The implementation of `bind` is where I'm stuck. Here's the code:

```
def bind[A,B](a: IO[A], f: A => IO[B]): IO[B] = IO {
  implicitly[Monad[Function0]].bind(() => a.unsafePerformIO,
      (x:A) => () => f(x).unsafePerformIO)()
}
```

This definition takes `IO[A]` and maps it to `IO[B]` using a function that takes an `A` and returns an `IO[B]`. I guess to do this, it has to use `flatMap` to "flatten" the result (correct?).

The `= IO { ... }` is the same as

```
 = new IO[A] {
  def unsafePerformIO = implicitly[Monad[Function0]].bind(() => a.unsafePerformIO,
      (x:A) => () => f(x).unsafePerformIO)()
  }
}
```

I think?

the `implicitly` method looks for an implicit value (value, right?) that implements `Monad[Function0]`. Where does this implicit definition come from? I'm guessing this is from the `implicit val IOMonad = new Monad[IO] {...}` definition, but we're inside that definition right now and things get a little circular and my brain starts to get stuck in an infinite loop :)

Also, the first argument to `bind` (`() => a.unsafePerformIO`) seems to be a function that takes no parameters and returns a.unsafePerformIO. How should I read this? `bind` takes a container type as its first argument, so maybe `() => a.unsafePerformIO` resolves to a container type?

Comment: Scalaz actually provides an IO monad out of the box now. import scalaz.effects._

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`IO[A]` is intended to represent an `Action` returning an `A`, where the result of the Action may depend on the environment (meaning anything, values of variables, file system, system time...) and the execution of the action may also modify the environment. Actually, scala type for an Action would be `Function0`. `Function0[A]` returns an A when called and it is certainly allowed to depend on and modify the environment. `IO` is `Function0` under another name, but it is intended to distinguish (tag?) those Function0 which depends on the environment from the other ones, which are actually pure value (if you say f is a function[A] which always returns the same value, without any side effect, there is no much difference between `f` and its result). To be precise, it is not so much that function tagged as IO must have side effect. It is that those not so tagged must have none.  Note however than wrapping impure functions in `IO` is entirely voluntary, there is no way you will have a guarantee when you get a `Function0` that it is pure. **Using `IO` is certainly not the dominant style in scala**.

> pure takes a value and turns it into a value contained in the
>   "container" type.

Quite right, but "container" may mean quite a lot of things. And the one returned by pure must be as light as possible, it must be the one that makes no difference. The point of list is that they may have any number of values. The one returned by pure must have one. The point of IO is that it depends on and affect the environment. The one returned by pure must do no such thing. So it is actually the pure `Function0` `() => a`, wrapped in `IO`.

> bind pretty much the same as map

Not so, bind is  the same as flatMap. As you write, map would receive a function from `Int` to `String`, but here you have the function from `Int` to `List[String]`

Now, forget IO for a moment and consider what bind/flatMap would mean for an Action, that is for `Function0`. 
Let's have

```
val askUserForLineNumber: () => Int = {...}
val readingLineAt: Int => Function0[String] = {i: Int  => () => ...}
```

Now if we must combine, as bind/flatMap does, those items to get an action that returns a String, what it must be is pretty clear: ask the reader for the line number, read that line and returns it. That would be

```
val askForLineNumberAndReadIt= () => {
  val lineNumber : Int = askUserForLineNumber()
  val readingRequiredLine: Function0[String] = readingLineAt(line)
  val lineContent= readingRequiredLine()
  lineContent
}
```

More generically

```
def bind[A,B](a: Function0[A], f: A => Function0[B]) = () => {
  val value = a()
  val nextAction = f(value)
  val result = nextAction()
  result
}
```

And shorter:

```
def bind[A,B](a: Function0[A], f: A => Function0[B]) 
  = () => {f(a())()}
```

So we know what `bind` must be for `Function0`, `pure` is clear too. We can do

```
object ActionMonad extends Monad[Function0] {
  def pure[A](a: => A) = () => a
  def bind[A,B](a: () => A, f: A => Function0[B]) = () => f(a())()
}
```

Now, IO is Function0 in disguise. Instead of just doing `a(),` we must do `a.unsafePerformIO`. And to define one, instead of `() => body`, we write `IO {body}`
So there could be

```
object IOMonad extends Monad[IO] {
  def pure[A](a: => A) = IO {a}
  def bind[A,B](a: IO[A], f: A => IO[B]) = IO {f(a.unsafePerformIO).unsafePerformIO}
}
```

In my view, that would be good enough. But in fact it repeats the ActionMonad. The point in the code you refer to is to avoid that and reuse what is done for `Function0` instead. One goes easily from `IO` to `Function0` (with `() => io.unsafePerformIo`) as well as from `Function0` to `IO` (with `IO { action() }`). If you have f: A => IO[B], you can also change that to `f: A => Function0[B]`, just by composing with the `IO` to `Function0` transform, so `(x: A) => f(x).unsafePerformIO`.

What happens here in the bind of IO is:

1. `() => a.unsafePerformIO`: turn `a` into a `Function0`
2. `(x:A) => () => f(x).unsafePerformIO)`: turn `f` into an A => `Function0[B]`
3. implicitly[Monad[Function0]]: get the default monad for `Function0`, the very same as the `ActionMonad` above
4. `bind(...)`: apply the `bind` of the `Function0` monad to the arguments `a` and `f` that have just been converted to Function0
5. The enclosing `IO{...}`: convert the result back to `IO`.

(Not sure I like it much)

Comment: How would I read this `val readingLineAt: Int => Function0[String] = Int => String {i: Int  => () => ...}`? E.g. "readingLineAt" is a value that returns a method that takes an Int and returns a Function0[String]. I can get that far, but I'm not sure about the implementation. is the `Int => String` some sort of anonymous function?

Comment: Sorry, mistyped/miscopied/mispasted. Fixed

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'm still working through this post (not a ton of spare time lately). I think you mean `val nextAction = f(value)` instead of `val nextAction = f(a)`