# Why doesn't Scala have an IO Monad?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming

I'm wondering why Scala does not have an IO Monad like Haskell.

So, in Scala the return type of method `readLine` is String whereas in Haskell the comparable function `getLine` has the return type IO String.

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419089/help-me-understand-this-scala-code-scalaz-io-monad-and-implicits) about this topic, but its answer it not satisfying:

> Using IO is certainly not the dominant style in scala.

Can someone explain this a bit further? What was the design decision for not including IO Monads to Scala?

Comment: `getLine` doesn't have "return type IO String". The type of `getLine` *is* `IO String`. There is no `->`, so it is not a function

Comment: @newacct Or it's a "nullary function". Either way is a valid way to think about it.

Comment: @Ben there are no such things as "nullary functions" in Haskell.

Comment: @Ben: See [*"Everything is a function" in Haskell?*](http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell).

Comment: @ehird There is a mode of thinking about Haskell where a function of type `a -> b -> c` is a unary function (as are all functions) of `a` that returns a function of `b` that returns a `c`. There is another mode of thinking in which a value of type `a -> b -> c` is simply a binary function. Much of the time this makes thinking easier. And in this mode of thinking, the concept of "nullary functions" means you can use the same mental model of what happens when you apply a unary function as when you apply an n-ary one; you get an (n-1)-ary function. I think both modes of thinking are useful.

Comment: @Ben: It is reasonable to say that `Integer` is nullary; however, it is not a function. Similarly, we could define a type being "depth *n*" to mean being nested in *n* `[]`s. `Integer` is depth 0, `[Integer]` is depth 1, and `[[Integer]]` is depth 2, but only the latter two types are lists.

Comment: (Indeed, not being a function is the *definition* of nullary, just as not being a list is the definition of depth 0.)

Comment: @ehird But in a hypothetical world where there were nullary functions they would behave exactly as non-function values do (in a lazy pure language like Haskell; other languages *do* have nullary functions that *are* different from non-function values). So in a case where it helps me to mentally model something in my code as a nullary function, I do that. Just as in Haskell binary functions don't really exist, I can still use the concept of a binary function as a mental model (although they do exist again if you go even deeper into the implementation, so go figure).

Comment: @ehird When I'm thinking about higher order programming, useful properties of n-ary functions do generalise down to nullary ones (or rather, useful properties of n-ary functions that result in (n-m)-ary functions generalise to when n = m). Including concepts like the "return type" of  "nullary function" that prompted this discussion. This contrasts with your "depth" of list nesting example, where an `Integer` has nothing useful in common with a depth n `Integer` for n > 0.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, it is valid and useful to use general reasoning about *n*-ary values, just as it is valid to use general reasoning about depth *n* types. For instance, `(: [])` takes a depth *n* list, and returns a depth n+1 list, so `Integer` *can* be reasoned about as a depth 0 value just like n+1 depth values. But that does not mean it is valid to consider `Integer` a list, or nullary values functions. There is nothing special about functions at all in this case.

Comment: @Ben: Additionally, relying on the perceived usefulness of induction in a certain context to justify inconsistency really seems like a rationalisation to me. But anyway, I've said everything I have to say on the matter, and this is really off-topic and not well-suited to SO's comment system.

Comment: @ehird You make good points, although I don't see the inconsistency. To bring it back to the original start, I just don't see the problem with viewing `getLine` as a nullary "thing" that when applied to zero more values evaluates to a value of type `IO String`, as long as it's understood that this is **one** model, not **the** model (and in particular this is **not** consistent with the model where all functions are unary). I'm happy to leave it at that.

Comment: We can also view as IO String as being `RealWorld -> (RealWorld, String)` which is a function.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because Scala is not pure (and has no means to enforce that a function is pure, like D has) and allows side effects. It interoperates closely with Java (e.g. reuses big parts of the Java libraries). Scala is not lazy, so there is no problem regarding execution order like in Haskell (e.g. no need for `>>` or `seq`). Under these circumstances introducing the IO Monad would make life harder without gaining much.

But if you really have applications where the IO monad has significant advantages, nothing stops you from writing your own implementation or to use scalaz. See e.g. http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/towards-an-effect-system-in-scala-part-2-io-monad/

**[Edit]**

> Why wasn't it done as a lazy and pure language?

This would have been perfectly possible (e.g. look at [Frege](https://github.com/Frege/frege), a JVM language very similar to Haskell). Of course this would make the Java interoperability more complicate, but I don't think this is the main reason. I think a lazy and pure language is a totally cool thing, but simply too alien to most Java programmers, which are the target audience of Scala. Scala was designed to cooperate with Java's object model (which is the exact opposite of pure and lazy), *allowing* functional and mixed functional-OO programming, but not *enforcing* it (which would have chased away almost all Java programmers). In fact there is no point in having yet another completely functional language: There is Haskell, Erlang, F# (and other MLs) and Clojure (and other Schemes / Lisps), which are all very sophisticated, stable and successful, and won't be easily replaced by a newcomer.

Comment: So the main reason is Java interoperability? Or why wasn't it done as a lazy and pure language?

Comment: @Antoras, the JVM and its byte-code has no built-in support for laziness and purity. This means that every call to non-Scala methods would have to happen in the IO monad and use strict parameters, which would make Java interoperability *very* difficult.

Comment: F# is actually more like scala - unpure and lazy only explicitly (but i don't have any expirience with F#, i could be wrong)

Comment: `>>` doesn't really do much regarding execution order in haskell, only `seq` and `pseq`

Comment: @alternative, so `putStrLn "First" >> putStrLn "Second"` doesn't have a well-defined execution order?

Comment: @pat Not that it doesn't have a `well-defined` execution order, just that the order isn't changed specifically due to `>>`. Also keep in mind that `>>` is for monads, not for IO, so any IO-specific details don't apply. Monads are not strict, this is why we have strict versions of different monads with different semantics.